# Needle in a haystack jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Basically, I'm producing a **JSON Array** dynamically to Javascript, I'm then doing an Ajax call which returns **JSON** data from an API, I want to check an value inside the objects from the **Ajax JSON response** to see if it matches with my **JSON Array**, I've tried doing the following :

***My Dynamic JSON Array*** - JSON.php

```
global $wpdb;
$Ids = array();
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "videos";
$idList = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `videoId` FROM `$table_name`");
foreach($idList as $ID) {
     $Ids[] = $ID->videoId;
}
echo json_encode(array('IdList' => $Ids));
```

***My Dynamic JSON output example*** - JSON.php

```
{"IdList":["47","55"]}
```

***My Dynamic JSON Array*** - Javascript

```
var Ids = null;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: pluginURL + "/JSON.php",
    data: "ajaxAction=getIds&rand="+Math.floor(Math.random()*10000),
    success: function(data) {
        Ids = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

So that's the code that's producing an Array of ID's that are stored inside my Database, I then want to use an **AJAX** call which returns an **JSON Response** from an API to check against these IDs, Here's the code that's returning the API response

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: apiURL + "video/" + Username,
    success: function(data) {
        Parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        jQuery.each(Parsed.user_media, function(i,v){
            id = v['id'];
            if(jQuery.inArray(id,Ids['IdList']) !== -1) {
               //this isn't working!
            }
        });
    },
});
```

***Example data output from the AJAX call***

```
{"user_media":[{"id":"2"},{"id":"44"}]}
```

As you can see I've tried to utilise the `jQuery.inArray()` to no avail, I'm not sure why, as I may just be parsing something wrong

Comment: Show us how `data` looks

Comment: `$Ids = $ID->videoId;` is wrong. You overwrite the value in each iteration. Also you don't need `jQuery.parseJSON`, you can specify the return content-type in the AJaX call, and it will be parsed automatically.

Comment: it should be `id = v.id`;

Comment: @Johan - I've gone ahead and done such

Comment: @DevZer0 It can be either or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `Ids` data is not getting set before second `ajax call`. Wrap second `ajax` call on first `ajax` call `success` like this:

```
var Ids = null;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: pluginURL + "/JSON.php",
    data: "ajaxAction=getIds&rand=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    success: function(data) {
        Ids = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: apiURL + "video/" + Username,
            success: function(data) {
                Parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                jQuery.each(Parsed.user_media, function(i, v) {
                    id = v['id'];
                    if (jQuery.inArray(id, Ids['IdList']) !== -1) {
                        //this isn't working!
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```